# Why Macbook Pro 2016 removes F1-F12 keys but the Fn key still there

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

Anybody know why in the new Macbook Pro 2016, they remove the <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd>-><kbd>F12</kbd> keys with the Touch Bar but the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is still there?

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> still turns `Touch Bar` into a function key row <kbd>F1</kbd>..<kbd>F12</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Fn is also used for the new Siri features as well.